# How to open a bash script in Terminator using a command line?

Tags: scripts

so basically I have a program called Terminator and I want to open a .sh script, however, I don't run to run it as root, I basically want to have Terminator run the script, using another command line, how can I do this?

Comment: Your going to have to explain how Terminator works. Ussually to open a file with a program the command would be `<program> file`. e.g. `gedit doc.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make terminator to execute a command with `-x COMMAND [option]`. So to run terminator with executing a shell script you can do the following:

```
terminator -x bash /path/to/script.sh
```

This will start a new instance of terminator and will automatically start the script in the bash and ask you for a password if necessary (e.g. when using a command with `sudo`).

Hope this helps.

Greatings, Darth Ravage